# I have an issue in python code snippet

Tags: python, boolean

a python function is reading the values perfectly if the value have double quotes in it but the same cannot be processed if we have no quotes at all.

```
def str_to_bool(text):
    if text.lower().strip("\"\' \t\n\r") in ("yes", "y", "true",  "t", "1"):
        return True
    return False
```

the following portion uses this function to read a value/key

```
for key in ["systemSDI", "systemOSN"]:
        if (key in facts) and facts[key]:
            provRequest.set(section, key, str(node.str_to_bool(facts[key])))
```

this is working if the value is like systemSDI: "YES" but not if systemSDI: YES 
I wanted the tweak the function in such a way that in both cases it should work

facts:

```
operatingsystemrelease: "5.8"
operatingsystem: OEL
system: cacr-TEST
systemLevel: TEST
systemSDI: "YES"
systemOSN: "NO"
```

Comment: no need of that if True: return True else return False in `str_to_bool`...

Comment: please provide `facts` so we can run your code.

Comment: I mean, a real code... Because the error could be there.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct:

```
>>> str_to_bool("YES")
True
>>> str_to_bool('"YES"')
True
```

So, if it's not working as intended, please check your input data.

By the way, your function can be transformed to:

```
def str_to_bool(text):
   return text.lower().strip("\"\' \t\n\r") in ("yes", "y", "true",  "t", "1")
```

Comment: if the line is like systemSDI: YES it fails ,

Comment: if the line is like systemSDI: YES it fails ,

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/strap/bin/boot_install.py", line 102, in <module>
    provRequest.set(section, key, str(node.str_to_bool(facts[key])))
  File "/usr/local/strap/lib/node.py", line 264, in str_to_bool
    if text.lower().strip("\"\' \t\n\r") in ("yes", "y", "true",  "t", "1"):
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'lower'
bootstrap configuration failed`

Comment: Try this: `node.str_to_bool(str(facts[key])))`